# Can Geomedia be automated using VBA?

Tags: vba, geomedia

Can I automate Geomedia using VBA?

The Geomedia training manual "Fundamentals of Geomedia Development Part 1" talks about automating using visual basic but I do not have Visual Basic.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ANY free IDEs, code or text editors and programming languages that can use .NET Framework.

You can FREE download Microsoft Visual Studio Community to develop on any .NET languages...

Comment: C#, VB, C++, F#...

Comment: Python, e. g. ))

Comment: Can Geomedia be automated using VBA?  Your answer makes no mention of VBA so should viewers of your answer assume that the answer to the specific question is No?